# auto start vnc in user context

Tags: lubuntu, vnc

so I have a vncserver with config in ~ for the one user I have on my box - me.  This is an old laptop and I really want to just put it in the cupboard and only interact with it through vnc.

If I run vncserver from a terminal shell, logged in as me - it works perfectly.  If I go to the lubuntu list of things to autostart, and say to run the vncserver - then I just get an empty X screen with just a cursor, no menus or anything.

Is there any way to basically say "run it in the context of me, whenever the machine starts up", or to otherwise achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Please provide release details  (Lubuntu has more than a single desktop)

Comment: its lubuntu 18.04.4 LTS